# how to create my own new plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I do not know about how to create my own new plugin in wordpress.
           so which is the best site tutorial to learn wordpress plugins.
           initially i do not known about wordpress plugins. but i known only few about wordpress. so anyone help me.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: before ask this kind of question first go for Google search

Answer (score 3):

[This Guide](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/30/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin/) should be sufficient for a beginner. From there you can get online books and tutorials.

EDIT:

There are also a bunch of tutorials that can be found [HERE](http://tutorialswebdesign.com/2012/01/09/create-wordpress-plugin-tutorials/). Also [see this](http://www.themepremium.com/tutorial-how-to-create-wordpress-plugins/) for a very basic plugin.

Good Luck!

Comment: any other best tutorial site r u known.

Comment: but i want to add my plugin page in settings.how do it?

Comment: @SANKARS26 If you have a specific question, ask another question. We can't guide you through a tutorial in comments. Just make sure you do your research and show us what you tried.